# ¿Como comparar un string en javascript para agregar un estilo?

Tags: javascript

buenas estoy intentando comparar un if else para agregar un estilo ( border), como ven en mi siguiente codigo agregar un id a un elemento para aplicarle el estilo, el estilo que funciona es el estilo que agrege por default, por si no se cumple nada en el if y else (por si existe un error o algo parecido).

```js
    var myElement = document.getElementById("demo");



 if (myElement == 'company') {

   myElement.style.border = '2px solid red'; 
 }

 else {
 myElement.style.border = "2px solid blue";
}

//este es el estilo por default
 myElement.style.border = "2px solid green";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Example CSS3</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>


<p id="demo">company</p>


<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas seleccionando el elemento pero te falta seleccionar su contenido (Esto lo puedes hacer con `innerText` o `innerHTML`), además el estilo por default deberías de agregarlo en tu `CSS` ya que al agregarlo al final de tu `JS` siempre se va a ejecutar de último por lo cual no se verá reflejado el resultado de la condición:

```js
var myElement = document.getElementById("demo");

if (myElement.innerText == 'company') {
   myElement.style.border = '2px solid red'; 
}else {
 myElement.style.border = "2px solid blue";
}
```

```css
#demo{
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Example CSS3</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>


<p id="demo">company</p>


<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.